# LGoodDatePicker - is is possible to highlight the date on hover

Tags: java

Does anyone know if it possible to highlight the date in the calendar panel of the DatePicker when the mouse hovers over it? I was able to find setting to change the color when hovering over that month and year and current date button but not for the date in the calendar.

Comment: Are you using the latest version ([11.2.0](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker)) ?

Comment: I am using 11.2.1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.